# URL amigável redireciona para index.php

Tags: php, url-amigável

Estou tendo problema para direcionar minhas url amigáveis para as páginas específicas. Quando clico em revendas-autorizadas por exemplo, ele está me levando para index.php

Tenho o código vars.php

```
 <?php
    //var_dump($_SERVER);
function parse_path() {
  $path = array();
  if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $request_path = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $path['base'] = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '\/');
    $path['call_utf8'] = substr(urldecode($request_path[0]), strlen($path['base']) + 1);
    $path['call'] = utf8_decode($path['call_utf8']);
    if ($path['call'] == basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
      $path['call'] = '';
    }
    $path['call_parts'] = explode('/', $path['call']);

    $path['query_utf8'] = urldecode($request_path[1]);
    $path['query'] = utf8_decode(urldecode($request_path[1]));
    $vars = explode('&', $path['query']);
    foreach ($vars as $var) {
      $t = explode('=', $var);
      $path['query_vars'][$t[0]] = $t[1];
    }
  }
return $path;
}



?>

<?php
switch($path_info['call_parts'][0]) {
    case 'aunimed': include 'aunimed.php';
        break;
    case 'revendas-autorizadas': include 'revendas-autorizadas.php';
        break;
}

?>
```

Não

E tenho no meu .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

      RewriteEngine on

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

      RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    </IfModule>
```

Dentro de cada página estou chamando

```
<?php require('vars.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Quando dizes "url amigável" é remover o ".php" do url?

Comment: Exatamente @Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nem precisa disso, só usar o `.htaccess` dessa forma:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
    #URL's Amigáveis - friendly urls
    RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Alterei o código, mas quando vou acessar a URL aparece: The requested URL /revendas-autorizadas was not found on this server.

Comment: Bem, ai você tem que colocar a outra url tbm (/revendas-autorizadas).

Comment: Na outra linha embaixo de `RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [NC,L]` é só colocar `RewriteRule ^revendas-autorizadas/?$ revendas-autorizadas.php [NC,L]` Por exemplo. E assim você te que fazer em todas as páginas que você quer url amigável. Outra dica é usar `[QSA,L]` ao invés de `[NC,L]`, porque ai dá para usar o $_GET a vontade...

Comment: Entendido. Agora funcionou. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: You're walcome!